# Apache DBCP connectioon pool, Who owns the connections

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

Is it possible to know which classes are currently using `Connection` objects created by `DBCP`?

I want to create a REST service to continually monitor where connections are being used.

Comment: I wouldn't do that.  I would not like a design that couples every application that uses a connection pool to a central, single point of failure service.  I'd have each one be autonomous and manage their own pools.

Comment: May be you misunderstood the purpose of the question, I want to create a health monitor endpoint. Among other things it should be able to provide information how many connections are being used and who is using them.

Comment: Maybe you don't know how to design microservices.  Health of a microservice shouldn't be centralized; each service should be able to tell you about its health.  Still a bad design, in my opinion.

Comment: Lets say that that the application collects it's own data and then sends it to some dashboard. Question is how does the application know where the connection is being used. What is the efficient way of collecting information about the connection usage. I'm using Spring Data and I won't ever see the connection object myself. That part is taken care of by Spring.

Comment: I'd get them from the Spring/Spring Boot health check.  Still no good reason to centralize.  Just return JSON: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html

Comment: Do actuator services provide which classes use connections?